# Which is better OS for Magento 2 Ubuntu or Linux Mint?

Tags: magento2

Currently, I'm using **linuxmint 20** for running Magento 2. But when I run any command or run async process ram goes to 95% and start to hang the system

Also, the issue with PHPstrom after opening multiple projects, system hangs.

```
Please note that I have enough system requirement i5 10th generation with 8GB ram.
```

Before I was using Linux mint 18 which working nicely without any issue.

Now I'm looking to change the OS. So I need your opinion to use the os for Magento 2 with PHPstrom.

Any comments or answers will be appreciated.

Comment: Centos is best as  OS.

Comment: How's magento on Centos ? @AmitBera

Comment: So far my good experience